# Elasticsearch switching from deprecated "_all" to "copy_to"

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-dsl, elasticsearch-mapping

I've been using the deprecated `_all` for mapping a field in Elasticsearch v7.6 and I think I should switch to `copy_to` as per [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.8/mapping-all-field.html#mapping-all-field)

However I'm not sure this is the right implementation, as some search results are slighty different than how it used to be.

**old field map**

```
"narrative": {
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "_all": {
            "type": "text",
            "analyzer": "search_synonyms"
        }
    }
},
```

**new field map**

```
"narrative": {
    "type":"object",
    "properties":{
        "tor_analysis_result":{
            "type": "text",
            "analyzer": "search_synonyms",
            "copy_to": "full"
        },
        "status_narrative":{
            "type": "text",
            "analyzer": "search_synonyms",
            "copy_to": "full"
        },
        "closure_narrative":{
            "type": "text",
            "analyzer": "search_synonyms",
            "copy_to": "full"
        },
        "tpoc_rejection_notes":{
            "type": "text",
            "analyzer": "search_synonyms",
            "copy_to": "full"
        },
        "analysis_results":{
            "type": "text",
            "analyzer": "search_synonyms",
            "copy_to": "full"
        },
        "full": {
            "type": "text",
            "analyzer": "search_synonyms"
        }
    }
},
```

I am also using `narrative.full` instead of `narrative.*` when doing multi-match searches using this field. Am I doing something wrong?

EDIT: search query

```
{
  _source: [
    'baseline',
    'cpcr',
    'date',
    'description',
    'dev_stat',
    'element',
    'event',
    'id'
  ],
  track_total_hits: true,
  query: {
    bool: {
        filter: [],
        must: [{
            multi_match:{
                query: "show",
                fields: ["cpcr","description","narrative.full","title","tor"],
                analyzer: "search_synonyms"
            }
        }]
    }
  },
  highlight: {
    pre_tags: [ '<es_highlight>' ],
    post_tags: [ '</es_highlight>' ],
    fields: { '*': {} }
  },
  sort: [],
  from: 0,
  size: 10
}
```

Comment: can u share ur search query?

Comment: Please check my updated question